# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I am trying to get get the folder path from user's selection and for each file I read it and return the data. However upon getting the file I cannot read the data for some reason that I have't been able to understand yet. The directory I am trying to read and render do exist. I have referred to the other similar posts as well.

```
readFolder() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openDirectory'] }, (dirFiles) => {
      console.log(dirFiles);
      if (dirFiles === undefined) {
        console.log('No file ');
        return;
      }
      const pathName = dirFiles[0];
      fs.readdir(pathName, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
          fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(`something went wrong  ${err}`);
            } else {
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

readdir returns filenames "a", "b", "c" etc.  You want `pathName + '/' + file` for "/path/to/file/a"

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was the fact that I hadn't realised the return values of 'file' which are just the names of the files as strings but not paths. Assinging `let filePath =`${pathName}/${file}`;` and reading it onwards solved the problem.

Comment: Actually, you should probably use `path.join(pathName, file)` to make your code platform safe.

Comment: Explain what?  Replace `${pathName}/${file}` with `path.join(pathName, file)`.  See the [path module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) for more info.  In general, you should use that module for manipulating paths and then it will work properly no matter what the path separator is (even on windows where it's `\\`) rather than doing your own string concatentation.